# Postgres 8.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) issue

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, postgresql

Every time I reboot my Ubuntu, my Postgres never gets started automatically and the `/var/run/postgresql` directory is never there on reboot. I have to manually create it and set the owner to postgre in order to successfully start Postgres every time I reboot.  What is the real issue here?

Comment: Hard to tell because you haven't given any information on how you installed it.

Answer (score 1):

/var/run/ on ubuntu by default use tmpfs, so after reboot all necessary file/dir should be created again using init.d script